# Wie grüßt man in der Schweiz?

Tags: salutation, swiss-standard-german

Wahrscheinlich kennen alle den Schweizer Gruß "*Grüezi*". Allerdings habe ich im [Schweizerischen Idiotikon](http://www.idiotikon.ch/Register/faksimile.php?&band=7&spalte=694) folgendes gelesen:

> "Gott Grüezi hört-me nümme gärn, Salü und Servus sind modärn"

In der Tat hört man auch *"Salü"* und andere Grußformeln. Welchen Gruß würde man im jeweiligen Kontext verwenden (Freunde, Kollegen, Familie, förmlicher Empfang)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grüezi ist in dem Sinne nicht modern, sondern einfach höflich und deshalb Standard wenn man eine unbekannte Person anspricht oder jemanden, mit dem man per Sie ist.
Es handelt sich also um eine Höflichkeitsform.

Wenn man mit jemandem per du ist (Freunde, Familie, Kollegen), wird oft mit einem der folgenden gegrüsst:

> Hoi Hallo Sali Salü Ciao Tschau

Dies ist keine abschliessende Liste, aber die häufigsten paar.
Je nach Dialekt und Gruppe, sind auch andere Grussformeln verbreitet (wie Beispielsweise das englische Hi).

Servus hört man in der Schweiz eher selten.

Answer (score 6):

Weitere höfliche, vielleicht schon etwas in die Jahre gekommene Grussformen wären:

> - Grüess Gott (wohl)
> - Grüessech
> - Grüezi wohl

Höfliche Grussformen nach Tageszeiten, wobei "Tag wohl" eigentlich immer verwendbar sein sollte, solange es hell ist:

> - Guete Tag
> - (Guete) Morge / (-n) Abig / (-n) Abed
> - Tag wohl

Auch diese Liste ist nicht abschliessend. Ausserdem gibt es je nach Region unterschiedlich verbreitete Formen des "Grüezi". Ich wohne im Kanton Zug und hier hört man alle möglichen Varianten, ohne dass die eine heimischer wäre als die andere. Hierzu folgendes Zitat:

> "Im deutschsprachigen Oberwallis, wo man sich weder mit östlichem
>   grüezi noch mit westlichem grüessech begrüsst, werden die nicht aus
>   dem Wallis stammenden Deutschschweizer abschätzig als Grüezini
>   bezeichnet." - [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BCezi)